# VB.net Adding 0 in the middle of a integer

Tags: vb.net

I have this integer. A = 100002 of 6 digits and i want to add 2 extra 0 in the middle so it can be a integer of 8 digits.

Result = 10000002

how can i do it?

Comment: Do you always need to add exactly 2 `0` characters at position 3?

Comment: The first thing to realize is that unless you're going to do math on it, it's not necessary that it be a numeric data type. You could easily handle this as a string and use the string functions to insert whatever characters you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split your number up into two parts, the left and the right side. Then add the zeros to the left side and put back the right side.

100002 -> 100 [left side] 002 [right side]

```
    Dim number As Integer = 100002
    Dim rightSide As Integer = number Mod 1000
    Dim leftSide As Integer = number - rightSide

    leftSide *= 100 ' Add zeros

    Dim newNumber As Integer = leftSide + rightSide
```

With this, 123456 will become 12300456.

Comment: Elegant way to do it without converting it to string and using some `Strings.` methods, which I first thought about... +1

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to answer this, meaning that your question is likely not specific enough to get the answer you want. For example, the_lotus's answer is of course correct (and a more practical solution, too). However, this solution will also yield the result you specify in the simplest possible manner, by subtracting 2, multiplying by 100, and adding 2 again:

```
Result = (A - 2) * 100 + 2
```

Since both of these very different methods solve the problem you have posed, it follows that you might want to pose the problem a bit more carefully. For example, if you want to work with numbers other than 100002 (which you haven't said that you do), this solution of course won't allow that. If you want a solution that applies to numbers with other than six digits, the_lotus's solution won't allow that in all cases, either.

Comment: Or even: `((num - num Mod 100000) * 100) + num Mod 100000`

Comment: @ParrishHusband The vagaries of the OP's problem statement offer fertile ground for imaginative and variegated solutions. :)